# error with roslaunch after build using catkin_make_isolated

Tags: roslaunch, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed cartographer as recommended [here](https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) . Then, I installed `rosaria`, `rosaria_client` in the same workspace using `ninja`. Then, when I went for `roslaunch rosaria_client rosaria_client.launch` I got following error.

```
   started roslaunch server http://anindya-Latitude-E7270:40633/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /RosAria/port: /dev/ttyUSB0
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.21

NODES
  /
    RosAria (rosaria/RosAria)
    RosAria_interface (rosaria_client/interface)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[RosAria-1]: started with pid [14198]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rosaria_client/interface]: can't locate node [interface] in package [rosaria_client]
```

My ros package path shows

```
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/anindya/catkin_test_2/install_isolated/share:/home/anindya/catkin_test_2/install_isolated/stacks:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

I also added

```
install(DIRECTORIES
 launch
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
```

in this package's CMakeLists.txt, but, no result. I am not sure what could be the reason behind this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289308/error-with-roslaunch-after-build-using-catkin_make_isolated/) by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2018-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like the executable hasn't been built properly. The launch file is working, it is just not finding the node. Have there been any problems during compilation? Can you find an executable `interface` in you install space?

Looking at [the `CMakeLists.txt` of Rosaria by pentang, branch master](https://github.com/pengtang/rosaria_client/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) (this is what I find, but you haven't specified where you got it from), there are no install tags. You need to install the node as well, similar to what you did for the launch files.

On an unrelated note: Seeing that you are still using Indigo, I would recommend to update to kinetic, or to the upcoming melodic...

---

**Edit**

I'd recommend you go through the [catkin documentation](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html), especially the part about installing C++ executables. There the respective commands are shown and explained.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on 2018-04-23**:
I tried the following after add_executable and target_link_libraries

```
install(FILES src/go_three_second  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}     )
```

this Error come:

```
 CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:133 (file): file INSTALL cannot find  "/home/anindya/catkin_test_2/src
```

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-04-23**:
see edit above.

**Comment by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on 2018-04-23**:
thanks a lot. It works now.